# Is there any way to be notified of new videos on Hulu for non-viewable shows?

Tags: email, notifications, hulu

I noticed that Hulu indexes some shows that are not directly viewable on the site itself. Instead, it links you to another site where you can watch the video. For normal videos you can see on the site, you can subscribe to them and be notified via email when new episodes are available.

Is there any way to do this with shows you can't watch on Hulu but are indexed by Hulu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clicker.com](http://clicker.com) provides similar functionality and indexes Hulu's videos.